# Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

The app compiles pretty nicely but in the console I'm getting the above-mentioned error. Now let me post some code.

**`user.service.ts`**

```
mport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { IUserService } from '../interfaces/user.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService {

  constructor(
    private strategy: any
  ) { }

  get currentUser$(): Observable<User> {
    return this.strategy.currentUser$;
  }

  public setStrategy(val: any): void {
    this.strategy = val;
  }

  public create(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.strategy.create(user);
  }

  public retrieveOne(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.strategy.retrieveOne(id);
  }

  // other CRUD methods
}
```

This one lives in the `CoreModule` module of the application and the module looks this way:

**`core.module.ts`**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UserService } from './user/services/user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AuthModule,
  ],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

I'd like to play around with what is already written and decided to do this in the app component, its ts file has a few methods and a constructor where I inject `UserService`.

```
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    this.userService.setStrategy(new FirebaseUserStrategy());
  }
```

My app module just imports `core.module.ts`.

Comment: The DI system is trying to inject the strategy, but has no idea what to provide.

Comment: @FatemeFazli How come? Apparently it's an interface which is clearly indicated by the "I". Why do I have "super" here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would you please elaborate a little more? I'm injecting `user.service` into the app component and then want to set a specific strategy. Still don't seem to get why it does not work.

Comment: What is unclear? The error tells you the DI system can't resolve the strategy that UserService's constructor requires. How do you *expect* it to get resolved? Maybe read though e.g. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection.

Comment: I suspect you just mean to have a private variable for the class. Don't put it in the constructor as an argument. Move it outside the constructor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ahahaha I put it in the constructor, sh1t. My bad...Thanks for pointing that out. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: @Silvermind yeah I've just realised it! Thanks.

Comment: Removing it from the constructor is the quick fix, but probably not the right one. Give the strategy a proper type and a default value, injected or otherwise, to avoid errors later on. It's not clear from what you've posted why you've decided to set a strategy in the component; that may not be ideal either.

Answer (score 0):

you could mark your strategy with @Optional:

```
constructor(
    @Optional private strategy: any
  ) { }
```

Comment: well yeah but it won't work now because I use the `setStrategy` method, so I should refactor that strategy parameter out of my constructor, but indeed if I pass the constructor a strategy it should work. The reason why I implemented it this way is prolly because I wanted it to work this way and then wrote the method which looks better.

Comment: No choice but to make the strategy public then